# Android XmlPullParser Wolfram|Alpha API

Tags: android, xml, api, xmlpullparser, wolframalpha

I am trying to figure out XML Parsing with results from the Wolfram|Alpha API, I've searched general questions about XmlPullParser in Android but seem to be unable to parse the XML data.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser() 
    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
    parser.setInput(response, null);
    parser.nextTag();            
    results = readFeed(parser);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can connect to the API fine and get a result back. http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/explorer.html
You will be able to see what results you get back.

With my basic request looking like this: http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?appid=xxx&input=What%20day%20is%20today%3F&format=plaintext

Now for parsing the inputStream:

```
private List<String> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws   XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "queryresult");
    List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        String name = parser.getName();

        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("pod")) {
            System.out.print(" In pod: " + parser.getName());
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        }
        else{
            skip(parser);
        }
    }

    return entries;
}

private String readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "pod");
    String plainText = null;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        String name = parser.getName();

        if (name.equals("subpod")) {
            System.out.print(" In subpod: " + parser.getName());
            plainText = getPlainText(parser);
        }
        else{
            skip(parser);
        }
    }

    return plainText;
}

private String getPlainText(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "subpod");
    String result = null;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        String name = parser.getName();

        if (name.equals("plaintext")) {
            System.out.print(" In plaintext: " + parser.getText());
            result = parser.getText();
        }
        else{
            skip(parser);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The results on my console look like this:

```
I/System.out﹕ In pod: pod In subpod: subpod In plaintext: null[null]
```

The code runs fine, but there are some issues:

1. It cannot find a value for the plaintext tag.
2. This seems to only loop through the first pod tag.

Answer (score 0):

- In your `getPlainText()` method, you are advancing the the `START_TAG` event, then calling `parser.getText()`.  I believe you need to advance to the `TEXT` event in order for `parser.getText()` to return anything.  You probably meant ot use `parser.nextText()`.
- You're not getting all the tags because of how you're using `parser.next()`.

  In `getPlainText()`, you loop until you hit `END_TAG`, then return.  Now `readEntry()` is in the middle of a loop, so the next thing that happens is `parser.next()` is called *again*. Since you were already on the `END_TAG` event, you end up skipping an entire tag.  You should be testing the event type against `parser.getEventType()`, which doesn't advance the parser.  Only call `parser.next()` when you've finished with the current event (includes deciding to skip).

  You are also exiting when you get an `END_TAG` event.  You really want to start out looping by testing for END_DOCUMENT, because apparently `parser.next()` may or may not throw an exception after the `END_DOCUMENT` event, depending on which factory you used to build the parser, because there are a couple different `XmlPullParser` factories.  Read more on this issue:

  [Issue 29931:  XmlPullParser.next() doesn't throw an exception after END_DOCUMENT is reached](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29931)